# Tailwind CSS different option for top based on screen width

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I want to have two options of top

Controller file

```
class SideMenuUser extends Component
{
    public $class;
    public $hideClose = false;
    public function mount()
    {
        if (stripos(Request::path(), 'dashboard')!==false) {
            $this->hideClose = true;
            $this->class = 'bg-white fixed sm:sticky top-16 sm:top-0 z-40 w-72 h-full transition-transform -translate-x-full sm:translate-x-0 sm:h-[calc(100vh-65px)] sm:w-full';
        } else {
            $this->class = 'bg-white fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 w-72 lg:w-80 h-screen p-4 overflow-none transition-transform -translate-x-full dark:bg-gray-800';
        }
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.shared.side-menu-user');
    }
}
```

Blade file

```
<div id="drawer-navigation" class="{{ $class }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-navigation-label"></div>
```

Here is the tailwind configuration

```
export default {
    content: [
        './vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
        './resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/views/**/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/views/**/**/**/*.blade.php',
        './resources/views/**/**/**/**/*.blade.php',
        './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js',
        './vendor/wire-elements/modal/resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './storage/framework/views/*.php',
    ],
```

When screen width SM: top-0 the others top-16. How do I achieve it? The code above is not working anyway. top-16 is overriding all screens. Need SM set as top-0

If it put directly to the blade file it works but it does not work from Livewire component where I need to build the condition there instead of blade file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default Tailwind value configurations, if I am understanding your question correctly, you want `top: 0` applied for viewports with width less than `640px` and for viewports of width `640px` and greater, you want `top: 4rem` applied?

If so, consider "reversing" the variants you have applied. Try:

```php
$this->class = '… top-0 sm:top-16 …';
```

This means `top: 0` for viewport widths `< 640px` and `top: 4rem` for viewport widths `≥ 640px`.

Comment: I did it and its still get the same result. However, if I put it into blade directly. It works. Seems the tailwind configuration does not build from livewire component but blade directly. I also uploaded the tailwind configuration currently I had

Comment: Consider checking the Controller file is covered by the `content` file globs in the Tailwind configuration.